# ntp + ntp loose synchronize each time in 5:00 morning

Tags: rhel, vmware, ntp, ntpd

we have a very strange behavior

we have 12 Linux redhat machines - redhat 7.x

two of these VM servers are loosing the time synchronize each day at 5:00 in the morning

after we restart the ntp , then sync return to normal

but what could be the reason for this strange behavior ?

Comment: try checking ntpd logs, if you cant find the logs execute the following command ` grep log /etc/ntp.conf` this should provide you will ntpd log location. default location either `/var/log/` or `/var/log/ntpsatats`

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in the system log near the time NTP synchronization is lost? You said the servers are virtual machines. See if the virtualization platform includes any clock synchronization feature: if you are using NTP, you'll probably need to make sure any "sync VM's clock with the host platform" features are switched off.

Comment: you said = make sure any "sync VM's clock with the host platform" features are switched off" , please advice how to find this parameter? , this parameter in the Vcenter? / else?

Comment: can you post your answer please so all folks will see it , and please explain how to disable the feature ? ( and from where ? )

Comment: Are you using NTPd or chronyd?  Chronyd is the default on rhel7 and handles time management on VMs better than ntpd.

Comment: in /etc/ntp.conf we have 5 lines with server and with the ip address and two ip's are answering to ping   , systemctl status ntpd is disabled but from timedatectl status we get output and also from  ntpq -pn   , so I think we are use - Chronyd i

Comment: Please post the relevant files instead of trying to describe them using English. Also please define what is your hypervisor and if the VMs are all in the same host.

Comment: yes all VM are on the same host